# problem with find function in Vector of Structure in C++ 

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I am trying to use the "find" function here. For that here's the code for  the '==' operator. But I am getting a  "too many parameters for this operator function" error at the word "operator".

Can anyone kindly help me out ? Thanks.

```
struct gr_log
{
   string name;
   string category;
   string description;
   float cost;
   bool operator==(const gr_log& l, const gr_log& r) const

   {
           return l.name == r.name;
  }

};
```

And:

```
vector<gr_log>::iterator it;
it = find (grocery.begin(), grocery.end(), "Sugar");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A member operator only takes one argument:

```
struct gr_log
{
   string name;
   string category;
   string description;
   float cost;
   bool operator==(const gr_log& r)
   {
       return name == r.name;
   }
};
```

Alternatively, you could write a `friend` operator:

```
struct gr_log
{
   string name;
   string category;
   string description;
   float cost;
   friend bool operator==(const gr_log& l, const gr_log& r)
   {
       return l.name == r.name;
   }
};
```

Also, you'll need to perform a `find` using an instance of gr_log because you can't compare a gr_log with a string like you're trying to do:

```
it = find (grocery.begin(), grocery.end(), gr_log("Sugar"));
```

Comment: In a struct there's no reason to make it a `friend`. Just define the operator as a nonmember outside the class.

Comment: What is the reason for `friend` ?

Comment: @a1ex07: `friend` gives the function access to `private` members of `gr_log` (or whatever class where `friend` appears). Since it's a POD struct, all the members are public, and `friend` does nothing but add confusion.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I know what `friend` means :) I just don't see a reason to use it in this particular case with no private members. I didn't see you first comment when I posted mine.

Comment: `friend` allows you to define a non-member function inside the curly braces of your struct. That way your operators are defined in a reasonable location in the text of your program.

Comment: I'm not sure that creating a gr_log temporary goes well with the intent of his program. See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
struct gr_log
{
   string name;
   string category;
   string description;
   float cost;
   bool operator==(const string& name) {
    return name == this->name;
  }
};
```

This creates a `==` operator (using the correct syntax for member variable; it compares the explicit argument to the implicit `this`), which compares a `gr_log` to a `string`. Since your `std::find` call uses a string as a comparison object, you should be good to go.

As an alternative, you can define equality operators outside of your class:

```
struct gr_log
{
   string name;
   string category;
   string description;
   float cost;
};
inline bool operator==(const gr_log& gr, const string& name) {
   return name == gr.name;
}
inline bool operator==(const sting& name, const gr_log& gr) {
   return name == gr.name;
}
```

Note 1: The `inline` keywords should be there if you are putting these in a header file, but not if you are putting them in a source file.

Note 2: Specifying both operator functions allows for the commutative property of equality.

Finally, in case this hasn't been hashed over enough -- the member equality operator takes **one** parameter, the non-member equality operator takes **two**.

Answer (score 0):

operator == should not be a member of your structure. Or if it is, it should take 1 argument and compare it with `this`:

```
struct gr_log
{ ...
bool operator==(const gr_log& l) const {return name == r.name;}
}
//or outside of the structure
bool operator==(const gr_log& l, const gr_log& r) 
{
       return l.name == r.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices: either a function `bool operator==(a,b)` **outside** of the struct, or a `bool operator==(other)` inside the struct.